# Displaying class access modifiers in netbeans project navigator

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

Is there any way to setup netbeans to display java class access modifiers and type (is it class, interface of enum) in project navigator (Projects window)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> "Is there any way to setup netbeans to display java class access modifiers and type (is it class, interface of enum) in project navigator (Projects window)?"

I thought it already does this. You just need to know how to read the icons and they're meaning

[image]

[image: Online help]
[image]

Also just putting your mouse cursor over the object in the navigator will give you the full javadoc

---

See [**This Link**](https://ui.netbeans.org/docs/ui/code_navigator/Navigator%20spec.html) for more help with the navigator

Comment: I know about navigator which will show me structure of file I have opened, but I want to see witch type of object is declared in file without opening it.